Lightbox for Bootstrap 5 and and srcset as output for the img
I'm building a website using BS5 where I have a gallery that uses a js which creates a lightbox using BS5
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bs5-lightbox@1.8.3/dist/index.bundle.min.js"></script>

The Lightbox works as it should, but I'm right now in the stage where I want to optimize the page concerning image-sizes using srcset. The problem is, that the js outputs the img with src but I would like that it uses srcset so I can use different pictures for different viewports when opening the lightbox on different devices.


/*!
 * Lightbox for Bootstrap 5 v1.8.3 (https://trvswgnr.github.io/bs5-lightbox/)
 * Copyright 2023 Travis Aaron Wagner (https://github.com/trvswgnr/)
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/trvswgnr/bs5-lightbox/blob/main/LICENSE)
 */ !(function () {
  "use strict";
  var t = {
      d: function (e, s) {
        for (var a in s)
          t.o(s, a) &&
            !t.o(e, a) &&
            Object.defineProperty(e, a, { enumerable: !0, get: s[a] });
      },
      o: function (t, e) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t, e);
      },
    },
    e = {};
  t.d(e, {
    default: function () {
      return i;
    },
  });
  var s = window.bootstrap;
  const a = { Modal: s.Modal, Carousel: s.Carousel };
  class o {
    constructor(t) {
      let e =
        arguments.length > 1 && void 0 !== arguments[1] ? arguments[1] : {};
      (this.hash = this.randomHash()),
        (this.settings = Object.assign(
          Object.assign(Object.assign({}, a.Modal.Default), a.Carousel.Default),
          {
            interval: !1,
            target: '[data-toggle="lightbox"]',
            gallery: "",
            size: "xl",
            constrain: !0,
          }
        )),
        (this.settings = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, this.settings), e)),
        (this.modalOptions = (() =>
          this.setOptionsFromSettings(a.Modal.Default))()),
        (this.carouselOptions = (() =>
          this.setOptionsFromSettings(a.Carousel.Default))()),
        "string" == typeof t &&
          ((this.settings.target = t),
          (t = document.querySelector(this.settings.target))),
        (this.el = t),
        (this.type = t.dataset.type || ""),
        (this.src = this.getSrc(t)),
        (this.sources = this.getGalleryItems()),
        this.createCarousel(),
        this.createModal();
    }
    show() {
      document.body.appendChild(this.modalElement), this.modal.show();
    }
    hide() {
      this.modal.hide();
    }
    setOptionsFromSettings(t) {
      return Object.keys(t).reduce(
        (t, e) => Object.assign(t, { [e]: this.settings[e] }),
        {}
      );
    }
    getSrc(t) {
      let e =
        t.dataset.src ||
        t.dataset.remote ||
        t.href ||
        "http://via.placeholder.com/1600x900";
      if ("html" === t.dataset.type) return e;
      /\:\/\//.test(e) || (e = window.location.origin + e);
      const s = new URL(e);
      return (
        (t.dataset.footer || t.dataset.caption) &&
          s.searchParams.set("caption", t.dataset.footer || t.dataset.caption),
        s.toString()
      );
    }
    getGalleryItems() {
      let t;
      if (this.settings.gallery) {
        if (Array.isArray(this.settings.gallery)) return this.settings.gallery;
        t = this.settings.gallery;
      } else this.el.dataset.gallery && (t = this.el.dataset.gallery);
      return t
        ? [
            ...new Set(
              Array.from(
                document.querySelectorAll('[data-gallery="'.concat(t, '"]')),
                (t) =>
                  ""
                    .concat(t.dataset.type ? t.dataset.type : "")
                    .concat(this.getSrc(t))
              )
            ),
          ]
        : ["".concat(this.type ? this.type : "").concat(this.src)];
    }
    getYoutubeId(t) {
      if (!t) return !1;
      const e = t.match(
        /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|&v=)([^#&?]*).*/
      );
      return !(!e || 11 !== e[2].length) && e[2];
    }
    getYoutubeLink(t) {
      const e = this.getYoutubeId(t);
      if (!e) return !1;
      const s = t.split("?");
      let a = s.length > 1 ? "?" + s[1] : "";
      return "https://www.youtube.com/embed/".concat(e).concat(a);
    }
    getInstagramEmbed(t) {
      if (/instagram/.test(t))
        return (
          (t += /\/embed$/.test(t) ? "" : "/embed"),
          '<iframe src="'.concat(
            t,
            '" class="start-50 translate-middle-x" style="max-width: 500px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>'
          )
        );
    }
    isEmbed(t) {
      const e = new RegExp("(" + o.allowedEmbedTypes.join("|") + ")").test(t),
        s =
          /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)/i.test(t) ||
          "image" === this.el.dataset.type;
      return e || !s;
    }
    createCarousel() {
      const t = document.createElement("template"),
        e = o.allowedMediaTypes.join("|"),
        s = this.sources
          .map((t, s) => {
            t = t.replace(/\/$/, "");
            const a = new RegExp("^(".concat(e, ")"), "i"),
              o = /^html/.test(t),
              i = /^image/.test(t);
            a.test(t) && (t = t.replace(a, ""));
            const n = this.settings.constrain
                ? "mw-100 mh-100 h-auto w-auto m-auto top-0 end-0 bottom-0 start-0"
                : "h-100 w-100",
              l = new URLSearchParams(t.split("?")[1]);
            let r = "",
              c = t;
            if (l.get("caption")) {
              try {
                (c = new URL(t)),
                  c.searchParams.delete("caption"),
                  (c = c.toString());
              } catch (e) {
                c = t;
              }
              r =
                '<p class="lightbox-caption m-0 p-2 text-center text-white small"><em>'.concat(
                  l.get("caption"),
                  "</em></p>"
                );
            }
            let d = '<img src="'
                .concat(c, '" class="d-block ')
                .concat(
                  n,
                  ' img-fluid" style="z-index: 1; object-fit: contain;" />'
                ),
              h = "";
            const u = this.getInstagramEmbed(t),
              m = this.getYoutubeLink(t);
            this.isEmbed(t) &&
              !i &&
              (m &&
                ((t = m),
                (h =
                  'title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer autoplay clipboard-write encrypted-media gyroscope picture-in-picture"')),
              (d =
                u ||
                '<iframe src="'
                  .concat(t, '" ')
                  .concat(h, " allowfullscreen></iframe>"))),
              o && (d = t);
            return '\n\t\t\t\t<div class="carousel-item '
              .concat(
                s ? "" : "active",
                '" style="min-height: 100px">\n\t\t\t\t\t'
              )
              .concat(
                '<div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle text-white"><div class="spinner-border" style="width: 3rem height: 3rem" role="status"></div></div>',
                '\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="ratio ratio-16x9" style="background-color: #000;">'
              )
              .concat(d, "</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t")
              .concat(r, "\n\t\t\t\t</div>");
          })
          .join(""),
        i =
          this.sources.length < 2
            ? ""
            : '\n\t\t\t<button id="#lightboxCarousel-'
                .concat(
                  this.hash,
                  '-prev" class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev h-75 m-auto" type="button" data-bs-target="#lightboxCarousel-'
                )
                .concat(
                  this.hash,
                  '" data-bs-slide="prev">\n\t\t\t\t<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>\n\t\t\t\t<span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>\n\t\t\t</button>\n\t\t\t<button id="#lightboxCarousel-'
                )
                .concat(
                  this.hash,
                  '-next" class="carousel-control carousel-control-next h-75 m-auto" type="button" data-bs-target="#lightboxCarousel-'
                )
                .concat(
                  this.hash,
                  '" data-bs-slide="next">\n\t\t\t\t<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>\n\t\t\t\t<span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>\n\t\t\t</button>'
                );
      let n = "lightbox-carousel carousel slide";
      "fullscreen" === this.settings.size &&
        (n += " position-absolute w-100 translate-middle top-50 start-50");
      const l = '\n\t\t\t<div id="lightboxCarousel-'
        .concat(this.hash, '" class="')
        .concat(n, '" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="')
        .concat(
          this.carouselOptions.interval,
          '">\n\t\t\t\t<div class="carousel-inner">\n\t\t\t\t\t'
        )
        .concat(s, "\n\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t")
        .concat(i, "\n\t\t\t</div>");
      (t.innerHTML = l.trim()), (this.carouselElement = t.content.firstChild);
      const r = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, this.carouselOptions), {
        keyboard: !1,
      });
      this.carousel = new a.Carousel(this.carouselElement, r);
      const c =
        this.type && "image" !== this.type ? this.type + this.src : this.src;
      return (
        this.carousel.to(this.findGalleryItemIndex(this.sources, c)),
        !0 === this.carouselOptions.keyboard &&
          document.addEventListener("keydown", (t) => {
            if ("ArrowLeft" === t.code) {
              const t = document.getElementById(
                "#lightboxCarousel-".concat(this.hash, "-prev")
              );
              return t && t.click(), !1;
            }
            if ("ArrowRight" === t.code) {
              const t = document.getElementById(
                "#lightboxCarousel-".concat(this.hash, "-next")
              );
              return t && t.click(), !1;
            }
          }),
        this.carousel
      );
    }
    findGalleryItemIndex(t, e) {
      let s = 0;
      for (const a of t) {
        if (a.includes(e)) return s;
        s++;
      }
      return 0;
    }
    createModal() {
      const t = document.createElement("template"),
        e = '\n\t\t\t<div class="modal lightbox fade" id="lightboxModal-'
          .concat(
            this.hash,
            '" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">\n\t\t\t\t<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-'
          )
          .concat(
            this.settings.size,
            '">\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="modal-content border-0 bg-transparent">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="modal-body p-0">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<button type="button" class="btn-close position-absolute top-0 end-0 p-3" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="z-index: 2; background: none;">'
          )
          .concat(
            '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position: relative; top: -5px;" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="#fff"><path d="M.293.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L8 6.586 14.293.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L9.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L8 9.414l-6.293 6.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L6.586 8 .293 1.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z"/></svg>',
            "</button>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t</div>"
          );
      return (
        (t.innerHTML = e.trim()),
        (this.modalElement = t.content.firstChild),
        this.modalElement
          .querySelector(".modal-body")
          .appendChild(this.carouselElement),
        this.modalElement.addEventListener("hidden.bs.modal", () =>
          this.modalElement.remove()
        ),
        this.modalElement
          .querySelector("[data-bs-dismiss]")
          .addEventListener("click", () => this.modal.hide()),
        (this.modal = new a.Modal(this.modalElement, this.modalOptions)),
        this.modal
      );
    }
    randomHash() {
      let t =
        arguments.length > 0 && void 0 !== arguments[0] ? arguments[0] : 8;
      return Array.from({ length: t }, () =>
        Math.floor(36 * Math.random()).toString(36)
      ).join("");
    }
  }
  (o.allowedEmbedTypes = ["embed", "youtube", "vimeo", "instagram", "url"]),
    (o.allowedMediaTypes = [...o.allowedEmbedTypes, "image", "html"]),
    (o.defaultSelector = '[data-toggle="lightbox"]'),
    (o.initialize = function (t) {
      t.preventDefault();
      new o(this).show();
    }),
    document
      .querySelectorAll(o.defaultSelector)
      .forEach((t) => t.addEventListener("click", o.initialize)),
    "undefined" != typeof window &&
      window.bootstrap &&
      (window.bootstrap.Lightbox = o);
  var i = o;
  window.Lightbox = e.default;
})();
//# sourceMappingURL=index.bundle.min.js.map
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" data-bs-theme="light">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1.0"
    />
    <title>Lightbox</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col gallery-padding img-hover-zoom">
        <a
          class="hover-background"
          href="https://tsd-trio.de/stage/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/background.jpg"
          data-toggle="lightbox"
          data-gallery="example-gallery"
          ><img
            src="https://tsd-trio.de/stage/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/background.jpg"
            class="img-fluid target"
            alt="Bandfoto"
        /></a>
      </div>
    
  

  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bs5-lightbox@1.8.3/dist/index.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>



Here is a currently working codepen example without srcset.
https://codepen.io/Anwyen/pen/poBVYBy
My JS skills are not good enough to 100% understand what's happening in the lightbox js so I would appreciate any help if its possible or if there is no way to do so.
